# How to sort an array of structs by struct's value, inside another struct?

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

this is a contract where a "board" struct nests an array of "participant" structs.
Every Participant struct has a score, which can be upvoted with a specific function.

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to implement a sortLeaderboard function that returns that nested array of structs inside Board, ordered by decreasing score (highest score struct comes first). References to tokens (irrelevant for this question) are because every Participant and every Board are a token themselves.

here is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
  pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
  import "./SongNFTfactory.sol"; 

  contract TestSort {

  using Counters for Counters.Counter;

  Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;


struct Board{
    string name;
    Participant[] allPart;
    mapping(uint => Participant) partById;
}

struct Participant {
    uint id;
    uint score;
}

mapping(uint => Board) public allBoards;

function addBoard(string memory _name) external {
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    allBoards[tokenId].name = _name;
}

function addParticipant(uint _boardID, uint _partId, uint _score) external {
    Board storage board = allBoards[_boardID];

    Participant memory participant;
    participant.id = _partId;
    participant.score = _score;
    board.allPart.push(participant);
    board.partById[_partId] = participant;
}

function voteParticipant(uint _boardID, uint _partID) external {
    Board storage board = allBoards[_boardID];
    Participant storage part = board.partById[_partID];
    part.score++;

}

function viewParticipant(uint _boardID, uint _participantID) external view returns(Participant memory) {
    Board storage board = allBoards[_boardID];
    Participant storage part = board.partById[_participantID];
    return part;

}

function sortLeaderboard(uint _boardID) external view returns(Participant[] memory) {
    Board storage board = allBoards[_boardID];
    Participant[] memory arr = board.allPart;
    uint l = arr.length;
    

    for(uint i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
        for(uint j = i + 1; j <= l + 1; j++) {
            if(arr[i].score < arr[j].score) {
                Participant memory currentPart = arr[i];
                Participant memory nextPart = arr[j];
                arr[j] = currentPart;
                currentPart = nextPart;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;

}
```

}

Comment: Do you really need to sort on chain? If you really need them sorted on chain I'd use [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) to keep the array sorted at all times.

Comment: thanks @Ismael I'm checking it out. As to your question: I just want to put a view function that sorts it out, doesn't have to sort the array on chain. But I do want a function written on the contract.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense having that function in the contract for that purpose, it will be easier to sort it off-chain. I can't test but the issue seems to be a problem with the for loop bounds `i <= l` should be `i < l` because `arr[l]` isn't valid. Similar thing for the other loop `j < l`.

Comment: yes, you might be right. I'll take off this question

Comment: You don't have to delete the question. Sorting is quite common and easy to have errors, and it might be useful to others.